# Excel-addin: Range.format.fill.color. how to distinguish between "white" and "none"

Tags: office-js

I noticed `Range.format.fill.color` return `#FFFFFF` (i.e, white) for both when a fill color is indeed white **and** when fill color is none.

How do we distinguish them?

Comment: Just wonder: is there case that Excel will display non-White color when fill color is set to None?

Comment: I don't think we have such a case.